# WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 403 Forbidden -+-+-

Tags: python, websocket, chrome-devtools-protocol

I want to debug an H5 page on an Android app, But When I connect the webSocketDebuggerUrl using websocket, it reports an error WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 403 Forbidden -+-+- . May I ask how to resolve this error?

1. Connect an Android phone to my Windows computer.
2. Enable developer mode on the phone.
3. Type chrome://inspect in the Chrome browser, it shows the webview pages. Type the inspect link, it opens a devtools and shows the webview page correctly.
4. Forward socket process to computer, using command adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract::webview_devtools_remote_17180.
5. Type http://localhost:9225/json in the Chrome browser, it shows an list.
6. connect the webSocketDebuggerUrl in the list

```
import websocket
ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect("ws://localhost:9225/devtools/page/625C5EB348BF3D8E0B359614B7003DE3")
```

7. it reports an error

```
>>> ws.connect("ws://localhost:9225/devtools/page/625C5EB348BF3D8E0B359614B7003DE3")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\work\MiniConda\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 253, in connect
    self.handshake_response = handshake(self.sock, url, *addrs, **options)
  File "D:\work\MiniConda\lib\site-packages\websocket\_handshake.py", line 57, in handshake
    status, resp = _get_resp_headers(sock)
  File "D:\work\MiniConda\lib\site-packages\websocket\_handshake.py", line 150, in _get_resp_headers
    raise WebSocketBadStatusException("Handshake status {status} {message} -+-+- {headers} -+-+- {body}".format(status=status, message=status_message, headers=resp_headers, body=response_body), status, status_message, resp_headers, response_body)
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 403 Forbidden -+-+- {'content-length': '239', 'content-type': 'text/html'} -+-+- b'Rejected an incoming WebSocket connection from the http://localhost:9224 origin. Use the command line flag --remote-allow-origins=http://localhost:9224 to allow connections from this origin or --remote-allow-origins=* to allow all origins.'
```

Based on the error message, it seems to be related to the permissions for debugging webviews, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

to solve this problem you need to add the flag `--remote-allow-origins=http://127.0.0.1:{port_browser}` when you go to start the browser

```
options = [f'--remote-debugging-port={self.port}', f'--remote-allow-origins=http://127.0.0.1:{self.port}']
if headless is True:
    options.append('--headless')
self._browser = subprocess.Popen([browser_path] + options)
```